# Writing to files issue

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, printwriter

So this may or may not be a dumb question but here we go!

So I'm trying to write to a file and it doesn't override but it writes over and over again so I need help.

Method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void writeFile(File file, String index) {
    try {
        boolean wri = false;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String str = scanner.nextLine();
            if(str.equals(index)) {
                System.out.println(index);
                scanner.close();
                wri = true;
                break;
            } else {
                wri = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(wri != false)
            return;
        out.write(index);
        out.write("\n");
        out.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it isn't overwriting the file, but rather appending to it on each call? If so, that is because of the `true` being passed in the `FileWriter` which indicates appending. But I'm not sure I grok'd the question correctly.

Comment: As implied by a comment, you are using the same `file` to write to (in the `PrintWriter`) as you are reading from (in the `Scanner`). Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: @KevinO Yes, I want to check if it's written first then if it isn't, then write to the file otherwise don't write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is full of errors.

- Don't use `hasNext()` with `nextLine()`. Use `hasNextLine()` instead.
- You don't close `scanner` if `index` is not found.
- You don't close `out` if `index` is found.
- You open file for writing, even if you don't need to write anything.
- You ignore exceptions.
- `if(wri != false)` is a very obscure way to write `if (wri)`.
- No need to wrap `FileWriter` in a `PrintWriter` if you're only using `write()` method.

Since you explicitly call [`FileWriter` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) in `append` mode, I'd assume you want to write `index` to file, if and only if file doesn't already contain that text.

Please be aware that your logic will not work if `index` contains line break characters.

Since you're only reading *lines*, you should use [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead of `Scanner`, since `Scanner` has a very large overhead.

As for your lack of closing the resources, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Your code should be like this:

```
public static void writeFile(File file, String index) {
    if (file.exists()) {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; )
                if (line.equals(index))
                    return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file: " + file, e);
        }
    }
    try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
        out.write(index);
        out.write(System.lineSeparator());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error appending to file: " + file, e);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
File file = new File("C:/temp/test.txt");
writeFile(file, "Hello");
writeFile(file, "World");
writeFile(file, "Hello");
```

*File Content*

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Works Perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

try with **false**

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
```

Comment: If you do that, the file will be cleared before the `Scanner` loop, so what would be the point of that loop?

Comment: That only writes the last thing I've said it to write.

Comment: Indeed has no meaning , i think he got the file with something written before to process it , anyway my answer shows how to escape append to a file while writing .

Comment: Which you would usually do by removing the second parameter, rather than hardcoding a `false` value. --- Since question is not asking how to write file without appending, this is not a answer to the question.